# How could Tosen know that Kenpachi was smiling?

Tags: bleach

When Tosen fights Kenpachi in the *Rescue Rukia* arc, Tosen uses his bankai to combat Kenpachi.

A while later, Kenpachi figures out how to defeat Tosen's bankai and smiles. Tosen somehow knew that he smiled (Because we heard his thoughts: "He's smiling?")

However, **Tosen is blind**. How could he have known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Tōsen attacks with Enma Kōrogi, He is not affected by it as anyone else (he can still smell and hear).
So when he asked why Kenpachi laughs it was because he could [hear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GviJk.jpg) him laughing.

Comment: Are you sure he *heard* him laughing? I was pretty sure he smiled.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, He was also laughing. You can see for example in this video in 5:59.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPZD320Km7I

Comment: I still haven't heard him laugh, but I guess if Tosen says....

Answer (score 4):

According to [his page](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Kaname_T%C5%8Dsen) on the Bleach wiki:

> Tōsen boasts a great amount of spiritual energy. His skill in the use of his spiritual power is evident, as he uses his spiritual sense to "see".

He uses his reiatsu (spiritual power) to sense things around him, for example, to know where his opponents are during a battle. He should also be able to sense what the others are doing in the same way. It would not be otherwise possible for him to be a Captain-class shinigami.

The heightened sense of what people inside his bankai space are doing could also be one of the powers he gets from the bankai, because he has complete command over that space.

Comment: It seems he didnt have to. He just could have heard it (so do I).

Comment: Yes, when Kenpachi was laughing, like you said in the other answer. But at other times, when Kenpachi was just standing idle, he would need some way to know where Kenpachi was otherwise he could not attack.

Comment: True. But it was not a question.

Comment: Yes, fair point.